# giving error while accessing method outside of class

Tags: python

```
class one(object):
    b=squares

def squares(self):
    print('hi')
```

getting the following error:

> NameError: name 'squares' is not defined

Comment: What are you trying to do?  When defining `one`, `squares` is not define, just as the message suggests.

Comment: Class definitions are immediately evaluted. You need to define  `squares` before you define `one`.

Comment: `squares` is being treated as a variable name. Variable names are symbolic pointers to regions in memory. However, squares was not initiated and thus it does not point to anywhere, since it doesn't exist. You also need to put your function call into the `def __init__(self)` 'constructor'.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Let me explain it. First code should go inside of methods, these methods can be combined into classes. You shouldn't place code in the class directly.

In Python when an object is instantiated the `__init__(self)` method is called directly. This method takes the `self` argument which will hold the attributes and functions available for this class. In our case, I added an attribute called `self.size = 5`. Then we call the `squares(self)` function. Notice we access it as `self.function_name()`.

Then in that function we pass the `self` argument. Notice how we can access the `self.size` attribute from this function.

```
class one(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 5
        b = self.squares()

    def squares(self): 
        print('hi' + str(self.size))

o = one()
```

---

If you want a generic function not tied to your object. Then you need to define it before the class.

```
def squares(a): 
    return a*a 

class One(): 
    def __init__(self, a): 
        self.num = a 
        self.example()

    def example(self): 
        b=squares(self.num) 
        print(b) 

obj = One(4)
```

Comment: I need squares method outside of the class.

Comment: def squares(a):
    return a*a

class One:
    def __int__(self,var):
        self.num=var

    def example(self):
        b=squares(self.num)
        print(b)

obj= One(4)